# Can @RefreshScope be Eager

Tags: java, spring, lazy-loading, eager-loading, spring-cloud

The new `@RefreshScope` in Spring Cloud is great.  But a side effect is that beans become lazily loaded.  Most of the time this is a non-issue, but eagerly loaded beans allow for DI, property value setting, etc. to be assured at startup time rather than later at runtime.  Is there any way to employ `@RefreshScope` AND cause the affected beans to be eagerly loaded?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this "problem" by implementing a listener that catches the Refresh event.
Then I iterate over every bean in the context and call the getClass() method. (Any other method call on the bean will trigger its instantiation - getClass() is convenient since it exists for all beans.)

```
@Service
public class RefreshListener {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RefreshListener.class);

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @EventListener
    public void onRefreshScopeRefreshed(final RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent event) {
        logger.info("Received Refresh event. Refreshing all beans...");
        for (String beanName : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            logger.info("Refreshing bean " + beanName);
            applicationContext.getBean(beanName).getClass();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.